# Output error with get_post_meta in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom metabox in woocommerce. It has been added perfectly. My ultimate goal is to call that custom field in a function and show it in the cart.php. So I coded :

For Custom field: [I would refer http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/] in this regard

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
     // Save Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

    function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

     global $woocommerce, $post;

     echo '<div class="options_group">';

      woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
      array( 
        'id'  => 'number_field', 
        'label' => __( '<strong style="color:#239804">Your Free Products</strong>', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => '', 
        'description' => __( 'Please enter a number', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type' => 'number', 
        'custom_attributes' => array(
        'step'  => 'any',
        'min'   => '0'
                ) 
        )
        );

       echo '</div>';

      }//woo_add_custom_general_fields

      function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
      $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['number_field'];
        if( !empty( $woocommerce_number_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'number_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_number_field ) );

       }//woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id )
```

It has perfectly fitted in the Product Admin Page. Now I am creating another function where I am creating a counter for cart.php

```
function free_products(){

global $woocommerce ,$product, $post;

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

$free_number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'number_field', true );

$free_product = $cart_item['quantity'] * $free_number;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $free_product, $cart_item_key );       
        }   

    }
```

In My cart.php when I add

```
<td class="product-quantity">
     <?php 

     echo free_products();
        ?>
   </td>
```

The output become zero in front end. Can anyone please help me what I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
    function free_products(){

    global $woocommerce ,$product, $post;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
    $my_var = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $free_number = get_post_meta( $my_var, 'number_field', true );


    $free_product = $cart_item['quantity'] * $free_number;

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $free_product);       
            }   

        }
```

Let me know if It is working for you or not.Its working for me.

Comment: Thanks @Rohil_PHPBeginner it worked. I now get actually I am mistaking the product_id

Comment: Problem was, It was not getting the post ID to retrieve the data.So We have given the product ID because product ID and the post ID both are the same.